# c++ getter method calling constructor

Tags: c++

I'm quite new to C++ and Opengl, and there are probably a number of things I'm missing here which is giving me the following problem:

Say that I have an MouseManager object which has a Point(x,y) to store its position. The default constructor sets this to Point(50,50). It has a method "moveMouse" which is MEANT to be updating this position.

```
void MouseManager::moveMouse(int x, int y) {
    cout << "values: " << x << " " << y << endl;
    cout << "BEFORE: " << position.getX() << " " << position.getY() << endl;
    position = Point(x,y);
    cout << "AFTER: " << position.getX() << " " << position.getY() << endl;
}
```

Through the cout statements, I have confirmed the following:

```
values: 614 188   //this is the actual mouse position being passed by glut
BEFORE: 50 50     //this is the Point values before the update
AFTER: 614 188    //this is the updated values
```

However, upon the NEXT update, the BEFORE reverts back to 50,50 - i.e. it didn't actually update.

```
values: 614 188
BEFORE: 50 50
AFTER: 614 188
values: 616 187
BEFORE: 50 50
AFTER: 616 187
values: 619 187
BEFORE: 50 50
AFTER: 619 187
values: 623 186
```

I've been trying to work out why this is, and whether I'm somehow inadvertently calling the constructor again, but I don't seem to be.

Currently my code is set up as follows:

1. OpenGL mouse func calls the gameManager Object which contains EVERYTHING, including MouseManager.
2. MouseManager runs the moveMouse Method
3. moveMouse uses the Point object to create a new Point(x,y) with the updated x and y positions.

   ```
   void callMouseManager(int x, int y){    //from gl
       game.getMouseManager().moveMouse(x, HEIGHT - y);
   }
   ++++++++
   MouseManager GameManager::getMouseManager(){    //from inside GameManager class
       return mouseManager;
   }
   ```

I have no idea what's going on, hopefully someone can help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
    #include "MouseManager.h"
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    MouseManager::MouseManager() {
        cout << "CONSTRUCTOR" << endl;
        position = Point(50,50);
    }

    MouseManager::~MouseManager() {
        // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
    }

    void MouseManager::moveMouse(int x, int y) {
        cout << "values: " << x << " " << y << endl;
        cout << "BEFORE: " << position.getX() << " " << position.getY() << endl;
        position.setX(x);
        position.setY(y);
        cout << "AFTER: " << position.getX() << " " << position.getY() << endl;
    }

    Point MouseManager::getPosition() {
        return position;
    }
```

Comment: Where else do you change or do anything related to `position`. Because you must be doing `position = Point(50, 50)` somewhere else.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the code tag to work in the comments, but I only ever ACCESS the Point object of the mouseManager. I store that in a new, temporary point by the line
Point mouse = game.getMouseManager().getPosition();

Comment: Please add changes to the question itself. Was also specifically referring to `position`.

Comment: done, but I'm not setting position anywhere that I can see. I made a change and started using setters to change position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function

```
MouseManager GameManager::getMouseManager(){
    return mouseManager;
}
```

returns a copy of `mouseManager`. Any changes you make are made on the copy. Change it to return a reference.

```
MouseManager& GameManager::getMouseManager(){
    return mouseManager;
}
```

Comment: It works!! Thank you so much :D 
I knew it had to be something like that which I wasn't understanding but I had no idea what it was because references and pointers are still so foreign to me. . .

Comment: @Astantos, You're welcome. if you are going to write anything more than simple programs for homework, it will be best in the long run to get a solid understanding of those fundamental concepts.